# Why is reputation and flair points differ?

Tags: discussion, reputation

When I click the flair link, there it shows a reputation of 180 for programmers.stackexchange. But at the top of the page it shows 320. So what makes this difference ?
I have done the reprecalc , and it gives me 328. Totally confused.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reputation in your flair is cached whereas the headline figure is more or less real-time.